# Different model on speech recognition

Tags: android, tensorflow, keras, speech

I have tried so much time to run this example project https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/speech_commands/ml and finally produced this tflite model https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVnR3.jpg using convert_keras_lite.py inside export direcory.However, i checked the tflite model inside assets directory in this android project https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/speech_commands/android. I found that the tflite model is different with the first one. https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8U69.jpg.

I tried to replace the tflite model inside assets android directory to the first tflite model, but the app suddenly crashed with this error code in Android Studio logcat:

```
2019-12-22 16:45:22.262 795-795/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.speech E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.tensorflow.lite.examples.speech, PID: 795
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.tensorflow.lite.examples.speech/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.speech.SpeechActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input error: Can not resize 1-th input for a model having 1 inputs.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3282)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1970)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input error: Can not resize 1-th input for a model having 1 inputs.
        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.resizeInput(Native Method)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.resizeInput(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:194)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.resizeInput(Interpreter.java:285)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.speech.SpeechActivity.onCreate(SpeechActivity.java:190)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7335)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119)**
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem! Find it really hard to fight through building and converting the model correctly. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Not yet. I still try and try so hard. Hopefully, this problem will be resolved.

Comment: I'll give it another go this night or tomorrow. I'll update you if I have breaking news.

Comment: Can you tell me what the name of the tool for the graph visualization is?

Comment: Use this https://lutzroeder.github.io/netron/ to visualize the model you created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I did not solve the problem yet but I think I discovered some things that may help:

Firstly, there is other code for a speech command example that is in the TensorFlow repo itself (not the dedicated example repo): https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands

It does not use keras like the one you are using and has no information about tflite conversion, so I guess that example was created before tflite was around. 
After looking at the [architecture of the (conv) model](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/models.py#L207) that was used there, I found out that it is the same architecture as the prepackaged tflite model in the android project and it matches the second imgur link you posted.

So it pretty much looks like the tflite model in the android project is a conversion of the model in the old example. And the model that results from https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/speech_commands/ml is not compatible with the android code at all, since the inputs are different.

And that is not surprising since the android code is pretty much copy paste from the [old examples android code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/SpeechActivity.java) with a few tweaks for tflite usage.

So I guess the best take is to work on the old ml code and convert the resulting frozen pb graph to tflite.

**Update**

I did it!!!
Here's how it works:

- Download the frozen graph from [here](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/speech_commands_v0.02.zip).
- Run the following in python

```
import tensorflow as tf

converter = tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph("./conv_actions_frozen.pb", input_arrays=['decoded_sample_data', 'decoded_sample_data:1'], output_arrays=['labels_softmax'])
converter.allow_custom_ops=True
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("model.tflite", "wb").write(model)
```

If you view the model with netron you'll see it's identical to the model that comes with the android example.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. What python and tensorflow version do you use? I tried in my python 3.7.6 and tensorflow 2.0 but it doesn't work as yours.

Comment: Yes, I have the exact same versions. What exactly did not work for you?

Comment: When i try **`tflite_model = converter.convert()`**, the error code suddenly appeared like this https://imgur.com/a/8NwNTjy. and i can't continue running the next code.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct `tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter`?

Comment: Yes. I follow your code step by step, since `converter = tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph("./conv_actions_frozen.pb", input_arrays=['decoded_sample_data', 'decoded_sample_data:1'], output_arrays=['labels_softmax'])` contain **`tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter`**. When i executed this code, there was no error message until i execute this **`When i try tflite_model = converter.convert()`** and suddenly got error message.

Comment: I got the same problem as well. tflite_model = converter.convert() give error code.